# list value in while loop is always out of bounds

Tags: python, while-loop, index-error

I am trying to combine overlapping intervals in a list to create a smaller list with only intervals that do not overlap. However, I am constantly getting an IndexError: list index out of range on my if statements.

I have tried using a for loop but that seems to be a step backwards since the length of the list in the for loop statement is static.

```
list = [(13,15),(-1,16),(12,17),(-5,-2),(2,5)]
x = 0
while x < len(list):
    if list[x][0] < list[x+1][0] and list[x][1] > list[x+1][1]:
        del list[x+1]
    if list[x][0] > list[x+1][0] and list[x][1] > list[x+1][1]:
        tuple2 = (list[x+1][0], list[x][1])
        list.append(tuple2)
        del list[x]
        del list[x+1]
    if list[x][0] < list[x+1][0] and list[x][1] < list[x+1][1]:
        tuple2 = (list[x][0], list[x+1][1])
        list.append(tuple2)
        del list[x]
        del list[x+1]
    x = x + 1

print(list)
```

The expected output is: `[(-5,-2),(-1,17)]`

Comment: can you provide your whole code. I am getting a bit confuse since `list` is a function in Python, and I am not sure what is your variable `x`.

Comment: 1) Don't use `list` as a variable name, it shadows the built-in `list` type and will cause weird bugs.  2) You have a lot of `x+1`s in this code, but `x` is allowed to go up to `len(list) - 1`; in other words, the max index that you try to access is `len(list) - 1 + 1`, which is always out of bounds.  3) Adding items to or removing items from a list as you iterate over that list is a recipe for disaster.  Usually the solution is to operate on a copy of the list.

Comment: List is the name of my list, but I just changed the variable name to list1. If x +1 causes the list to go out of bounds, how do I go about calling the next element in the list while I'm iterating it?

Comment: When x == len(list) -1 of curse using x + 1 will cause the error you are at the last element all ready.

Comment: Just curious. If you delete index `x`, won't the content of the list shift up? Is it right to delete `x+1` after `x` then?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you stick with the variable name `list` (which you should change), you can only iterate to the length of that list-1 because you are adressing it inside the loop with a `x+1`:

```
x = 0
while x < (len(list)-1):
    if list[x][0] < list[x+1][0] and list[x][1] > list[x+1][1]:
        del list[x+1]
    if list[x][0] > list[x+1][0] and list[x][1] > list[x+1][1]:
        tuple2 = (list[x+1][0], list[x][1])
        list.append(tuple2)
        del list[x]
        del list[x+1]
    if list[x][0] < list[x+1][0] and list[x][1] < list[x+1][1]:
        tuple2 = (list[x][0], list[x+1][1])
        list.append(tuple2)
        del list[x]
        del list[x+1]
    x = x + 1

print(list)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't run this code until `x < len(list)`. It needs to be `x < len(list) - 1`

```
list = [(13,15),(-1,16),(12,17),(-5,-2),(2,5)]
x = 0
while x < len(list) -1 :
    print(x)
    if list[x][0] < list[x+1][0] and list[x][1] > list[x+1][1]:
        del list[x+1]
    if list[x][0] > list[x+1][0] and list[x][1] > list[x+1][1]:
        tuple2 = (list[x+1][0], list[x][1])
        list.append(tuple2)
        del list[x]
        del list[x+1]
    if list[x][0] < list[x+1][0] and list[x][1] < list[x+1][1]:
        tuple2 = (list[x][0], list[x+1][1])
        list.append(tuple2)
        del list[x]
        del list[x+1]
    x = x + 1

print(list)
```